# Three.JS Apply Textures to Portion of Sphere

Tags: 3d, three.js, webgl

*EDIT: I have decided that applying a texture to a portion of the sphere is the correct approach, but do not know how to implement it. I was going to open a new question, but felt it better for posterity to fix this one so that someone else could be helped.*

[see original question here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14142790/revisions)...

I am using a texture which was created using a Canvas element as it's image. It is simple to apply this texture to the whole sphere, but I am trying to apply this texture to only part of the sphere.

I have been able to achieve this by increasing the size of the Canvas, bordering my image with transparent space. However, this increases the size of the texture as well, to an unacceptable size. The transparent space also takes up texture memory and most clients cannot handle the size of textures created... Especially when I am trying to make very small, high-res textures; because the smaller and higher-res the texture is, the more transparency I must wrap it in...

Anyway, apparently there is something called "UVs" in 3D Graphics which allow just such a thing to be done... I am not sure how to implement such a solution in THREEJS.

This is how I am making my Texture/Material:

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();

geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(500, 50, 50);

texture = new THREE.Texture(document.getElementById('myCanvas'));
texture.needsUpdate = true;
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: texture
});
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);
```

How can I change it so the texture only applies to a section of the sphere?

I have seen this: [How to map texture image onto a part of a sphere, or how to cut out (intersect) a rectangle of a sphere's surface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775889/how-to-map-texture-image-onto-a-part-of-a-sphere-or-how-to-cut-out-intersect)

But my inexperience with 3d graphics leaves me helpless to understand the answer...

**Should I be learning more about Shader programming before proceeding with this project?**

**I have made a JSFiddle outlining this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/RCmBU/**

**How can I apply the black canvas to only the portion of the sphere indicated by the red dots?**

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Similar question, with solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870075/partial-equirectangular-panorama-three-js

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use different 'level of detail' models to provide the best textures depending on client capabilities. I dont know if this fits to your application but maybe it's worth to take a look:

[LOD example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_lod.html)

Comment: Hey thanks! I didn't know that existed, but unfortunately it leaves me in the same boat.

I essentially had already implemented this myself, when the user zooms in I can provide various levels of detail.

My question is about how to create the LOD object at the closest zoom level... My problem is that the texture is too large to buffer @ this zoom level, so I can only show part of the texture.

But I don't know how to only show part of the texture on the sphere!

Comment: If you want to create a high scalable shpere like e.g. a view of the earth you surly need to cut the texture in parts. Then you request the part that you curently need (depending on zoom and position) from your server application and apply it as texture on your sphere.

Comment: I'm using an SVG for the image of the texture, so instead of requesting from the server I just re-rasterize the texture at a higher resolution... The part I'm having trouble with is how to apply the texture to only the required part of the sphere. I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rWDRG/)... I think that mostly explains it, I'd like the texture to only be placed between the red markers.

Comment: What do you mean? It's blank for you??

Answer (score 0):

use 2 canvas:

1 from svg to canvas

1 from canvas to smaller canvas

EDIT:the uvs decide where it will be placed on the sphere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have tried this approach, but how do I apply the smaller canvas to only a portion of the sphere? When I apply the small canvas as a texture to the sphere it stretches the texture to the whole sphere...

Comment: if you have the visible portion, then calculate the uvs for that and update the sphere at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, my 3d graphics skills are not very good... Can you steer me in the direction of how to calculate UVs and update the sphere using THREE.JS? Or do I need bare metal WebGL for this?

Comment: CAn you generate a jsfiddle for this then I will look into this??

Comment: Just noticed that THREE.Texture has a mapping property ([see here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/textures/Texture.js))... But, by default it is simply defined as a blank function... Thanks for any help you can provide!!

Comment: Yes, definitely. I'll make one later today though if you don't mind... Thanks again!! PS: no rush on an answer :)

Comment: [This is very basic, but if you can show me how to do this then my problem will be solved! Sorry it took so long, again no rush on reply... Thanks!!](http://jsfiddle.net/rWDRG/)